# Is it possible to prove mathematical statements including factorials with z3?

Tags: z3, maxima, theorem-proving, wolframalpha

I am trying to prove the following

[image]

wolfram alpha seems to be able to discern that it is indeed [true](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5En%20-%20n%20-%201%20=%20sum(binomial(n,k),%20k,%202,%20n)), although it doesn't present a proof, and maxima can't decide (no surprises there):

```
declare(n, integer) $
assume(n > 0) $
is(equals(2^n - n - 1 - sum(binomial(n,k), k, 2, n), 0));
=> unknown
```

Now I thought I would bring out the big guns and try Z3 (even though I have only done the tutorial), but I got stuck at trying to tell it about factorials. Are these kinds of proofs above Z3's paygrade?

EDIT: The particular problem is not important. I am just trying to research the tools that can deal with this family of problems.

EDIT2: Fixed wolfram alpha link.

Answer (score 1):

This is well outside the scope of what Z3 is targeted for. 
There is no built-in understanding of factorials, binomials. 
It performs very limited reasoning about exponents.

Comment: Thanks, is there another tool (besides mathematica) about these kinds of things?

Answer (score 1):

Maxima has a package called `simplify_sum` which can apply a lot of identities and reduce many summations to other expressions.

```
(%i65) load (simplify_sum);
(%o65) /usr/share/maxima/5.39.0/share/solve_rec/simplify_sum.mac
(%i66) simplify_sum (sum(binomial(n,k), k, 2, n));
                     n
(%o66)              2  - n - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maxima also seems to be able to discern that it's true. Try

```
sum(binomial(n,k),k,2,n),simpsum;
```

Comment: `simplify_sum` is a lot more powerful than `simpsum`. I.e. `load(simplify_sum);` and then `simplify_sum(sum(...));`.